# What audio formats does the iPhone AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID support?

Tags: iphone, audio

I tried WAV but that failed, although I've seen example code using WAV.

I found an AIFF in another example which worked.

I'm planning on buying sounds for my app, and I want to know which format to go for.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at `AVAudioPlayer`, that’s a fairly nice sound playback API. If your WAV did not work, did it have the right endianity and sample resolution? You should be safe with little-endian sampled at 44.1 kHz, mono or stereo. You can buy in almost any format, the conversion quite very easy and can be done using free tools like `afconvert`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .WAV format sounds if the audio properties are acceptable to iOS.  What makes them acceptable you ask?  Well, I don't know the full list of metrics, but I do know I am successfully using files sampled at 8kHz, 16-bit PCM, mono.